ROS Robot turning left and right when I give it a goal in RViz
I am working in ROS Kinetic on a four-wheeled robot. I'm trying to get the robot to move toward a goal. In RViz, path planning is fine as it draws the intended path for the robot to reach the goal. However, when I give it a goal, the robot would first turn to face the direction of the beginning of the path, then it would stay stationary, turning left, then right, then left, and so on... For instance, if the robot faces north and I give it a goal somewhere south-east, it will first move in a small semi-circle toward the goal. Once it's facing the direction of the goal, it stops moving forward and just rotates left and right.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please ask if you need specific information because I'm not sure what is needed. I have my planner files. Planner.yaml, costmap.yaml, costmap_common.yaml, costmap_exploration.yaml, costmap_global_laser.yaml, costmap_global_static.yaml, costmap_local.yaml. Does any of these need to be changed?
I ran rostopic echo cmd_vel and only angular velocities were published during the robot's rotation, so it can't be a hardware issue.
